# Prove that there exists an $m$ such that for any $n>m$ there exists at least one prime between $c_n$ and $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $c_n$ be the $n$-th composite. Then the problem is to prove that-

> $\pi(c_n)-\pi(n)>0$ $\forall n>m$

I have tried to progress in the problem using an elementary approach. So far I have been able to prove the following trivial results-

1. For any $n>7$ the composite $c_n$ satisfies the inequality $2n>c_n>n$.
2. $\pi(c_n)=c_n-n-1$
3. $\pi(x)\geq \pi(p)$ $\iff$ $x \geq p$. Where $p$ is a prime. Notice that when the R.H.S always implies L.H.S. To prove the converse we note that $\pi(x) > \pi(p)$ $\implies$ $x>p$. The problem occurs when $\pi(x) = \pi(p)$. In that case if $x<p$ then it would imply that $\pi(x) < \pi(p)$, contradicting our hypothesis. Hence proved.
4. The $\pi(c_n)$-th prime is strictly less then $c_n$ for any $n>7$.
5. $c_n$$_-$$_\pi$$_($$_n$$_)$$_-$$_1$ $=$ $n-1$ $\iff$ $n$ is a prime and $c_n$$_-$$_\pi$$_($$_n$$_)$$_-$$_1$ $=$ $n$ $\iff$ $n$ is a composite.
6. Using 5 it can be proved that $c_n$ $\geq$ $n+\pi(n)+1$.

But what I want is strict inequality. I have proved that the function $\Psi(n)=c_n-n-\pi(n)-1$ is increasing between two consecutive primes.

Notice that the statement of the problem is equivalent to the following statement-

> Prove that the $\pi(c_n)$-th prime is strictly greater then $n$ for any $n > m$.

Actually I have borrowed the problem from the AoPS site. For the actual post see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=588724.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I do not have elementary solution, but I use Prime Number Theorem.
The version I use is:
$$
\pi(x)= \textrm{Li}(x) + O(x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x}))$$
$$
=\frac{x}{\log x} + \frac{x}{\log^2 x} + O(\frac{x}{\log^3 x}).
$$

I tried using 2. of your observation. 
$$
\pi(c_n)=c_n-n-1.
$$
Thus, 
$$
c_n-n-1 = \frac{c_n}{\log c_n} + \frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} + O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}).
$$
Then we have
$$
n=c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}).
$$
Now, we estimate $\pi(n)$ by the above formula:
$$
\pi(n)=\frac{ c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n})}{\log( c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}))}+\frac{ c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n})}{\log^2(c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}))}+O(\frac{ c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n})}{\log^3(c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}))})
$$
$$
=\frac{c_n}{\log(c_n-\frac{c_n}{\log c_n}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}))}-\frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} + \frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n} + O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n})
$$
$$
=\frac{c_n}{\log c_n} +O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}).
$$
Therefore, 
$$
\pi(c_n)-\pi(n) = \frac{c_n}{\log^2 c_n}+O(\frac{c_n}{\log^3 c_n}).
$$
Since $c_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have the result.

Comment: I have actually tried to prove it in your way. But if you have seen the link, you may have noticed that the problem was posted in the *Olympiad Section* of AoPS. I thought that there may be some 'olympiad level' solution of the problem but I couldn't find it. What I simply want is an 'olympiad level' solution of the problem.

Comment: I do not expect that such solution exists. If so, it would be extremely lengthy. Simply because, $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)>0$ requires a a lot of work, even though it is much less intricate than this.

Comment: Furthermore, your proof proves my first statement clearly enough but how does it prove the second statement can you tell me? Also notice that my problem will be completely solved if we can show that the function $\Psi(p_n)=c_{p_n}-p_n-n-1$ is increasing.

Comment: I did not care about second statement because you said they are equivalent.

Comment: I have also made another one conjecture. Which is simply that-"There exists some $m$ such that for every $n$ $>$ $m$, there exists at least one prime between $c_n$ and $2n$". Can you prove this without using PNT? If you can then post your answer.